# NSLog display details [xxxx,yyyy]

Tags: nslog

I'm debugging a third part app using NSLog and I always find this string within the console:

```
2013-12-27 14:44:36.031 MyApp[3107:3443] some text
```

What does the two number within square brackets represent?

Are they related to thread number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is the Process ID and the second one is related to the thread (Thread ID?)